# Error on uploading Crystal Report to server

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

> Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Check This Solution. It is allready posted in StackOverflow.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10001310/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-crystaldecisions-reportappserver-clientdoc


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10001310/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-crystaldecisions-reportappserver-clientdoc

Comment: Google (or any search engine for that matter) is your friend. A simple search on Google fetches me numerous answers :-)