# Where to find CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

Can you please share me, where can i download crystal report decision redistributable package.
I found below one, but it shows for VS 2005.

https://tcsoftware.net/blog/2011/05/crystal-reports-redistributable-download-net-2005/

I am using - VS 2012 on x64 machine - webapplication. and want to display RPT file.

I need this "CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc" DLL into GAC.

Please share me link where i can download related MSI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi here you can find the redistributable packeges for crystal reports 2011

http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824

Comment: I have installed - redistributable package and i found clientdoc dll is installed into gac assembly.But though, while "ReportDocument" statement execute then it gives an error about could not load clientdoc dll and informat issue.

Comment: have you checked this other post? maybe it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10001310/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-crystaldecisions-reportappserver-clientdoc