# Could not load file or assembly CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2017

I have a similar error than this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10001310/196526) or this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38025601/196526) but my question is different. I get the error on my local machine. This is a web application that need to print some reports. My error message is

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer, Version=13.0.2000.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I installed the **Nuget package Crystal.Reports.Essentials** by Jackes David but I didn't installed the **Crystal report runtime** for Visual Studio. I know installing the Crystal Report runtime will probably resolve my issue but I Don't want to install the Crystal report runtime because I want to be able to deploy my solution on cloud server and you canot always install third party exe on that kind of servers. I think It will be the same problem for unit testing. I cannot install the runtime each time I create a Virtual machine for testing.

Am I right or I must install this runtime?

Comment: The message is correct. There is no 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' in my system. This file is not in the Nuget package Crystal.Reports.Essentials